# Netsuite suitescript 1.0 query , for storing dynamically created ui objects and editing them back

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a questions related to suitescript 1.0 , which i am facing while developing in netsuite.

i have created a custom record on which i have added a sublist (inlineeditor) dynamically in the runtime using beforeLoad function (through form enhancement). The sublist contains two columns

1) text field ( a text field : in which user will type in some values)

2) CRM fields (a select field :in which user can select all the field values from the record type through which this custom record is initiated. the parent record might be customer/lead/prospect...etc)

Now when i save the record , i store all the values corresponding to text fields in a hidden custom field(long-text)  already defined in that custom record type which is of type "long-text" as comma separated values and same for the CRM fields.  (using the saveRecord() function in client script)

So that i can have a real backend model for the values that user input into the form , as the dynamically created UI objects are not persisted into record.

Now when i edit that record again through ui, i want my values to be again populated into this form as it is , by reading values from comma-separated values which i stored using sublist.setlineitemvalues() API ,  but only the text field(text field in the sublist) gets populated not the CRM field (which is a select type)

What should i do to populate the values into this select field ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nlapiInsertSelectOption` with Clientscript on the select field dynamically inserted during the beforeLoad. If this is a sublist select field then use `nlapiInsertLineItemOption` instead.

Comment: i have a little doubt here ..
suppose user input three line items 
line item 1 : text field "aa" , select field "salesrep"
line item 2 :text field "bb" select field "probablity"
line item 3 : text field "cc" select field "budget"
now i stored them as comma separated values in the hidden custom field in after saveRecord client script , as textfields= "aa,bb,cc" and crm_firlds = "salesrep,probablity,budget" .
This api nlapiInsertLineItemOption doesnt have linenum in the parameter so how can i populate values in the select fields in all the lineitems the dynamic sublist have ?

Comment: Use a stringified JSON instead of a comma separated value list. Something like {salesrep:'aa', probability:'bb', budget:'cc'}

Comment: I would just straight up get the values, create an object and then use JSON.stringify(myObj) to turn the Object into a string and then save that into your perm field. Then to turn the string back into object use JSON.parse  and you can use that to populate your select field.

Comment: The api nlapiinsertLineItemOption simply add a select option in my select field , whereas i wanted to the string value to be appear in the select field

Comment: Once you have populated the options then use nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue to set the values to the internal ids saved.
Also you can set selected as true for the option that you want to be selected by default: http://i.imgur.com/0UxDBki.png